# Haskell Pattern Matching: Specifying the number of elements in a list

Tags: haskell

So i am currently working with Haskell at my college, but kinda struggling with pattern-matching and to be more specific i'll give the program, that i am to solve:

My function is awaiting a list of lists ( with each list containing at least 3 elements ) and in each list the second element is replaced with the number of the third element.

Example:

`[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,10]]` should become `[[1,3,3],[4,6,6,7],[8,10,10]`

So far I've made the following:

```
 f [] = []
 f [[x]] = []
 f [[x,y]] = []
 f [[x,y,z]] = [[x,z,z]]
 f ([x,y,z]:xs) = [x,z,z]:f(xs)
```

My questions are:

1. How can i identify, that some lists may contain more than 3 elements and that the list must remain the same, only the 2nd element changes.
2. How can i make the recursion, so that it handles exceptions (for example the first list has 4 elements).
   Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It may help to first write the function that swaps the second value in a list with the third.

```hs
swap (x:y:z:rest) = x:z:z:rest
swap xs = xs
```

In the above, `x:y:z:rest` matches a list of at least length 3. The value of `rest`, since it is at the end of the pattern, will match any kind of list, both empty and full. The second pattern match of `xs` is a catch-all for any other type of list, which will just return the same list if it is less than 3 items long.

From there, you can write `f` in terms of mapping over the outer list and applying `swap`:

```hs
f = map swap
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast and useful response!